# AutoCAD plotter resets to None when selecting an OCE TCS500

Tags: printing, autocad

We have a few users who cannot plot from AutoCAD to any of our OCE TCS500s.
The programs affected are AutoCAD 2008/9, LT 2008 and Trueview 2009.

When selecting the a TCS500 plotter in ACAD, on 2009 it resets to None without any alert, but on 2008 it throws up the following:

> The plotter configuration cannot be
>   used for one of these reasons: the
>   driver cannot be found, or the driver
>   has a problem. The None plot device
>   has been substituted.

We've tried re-installing the plotters from the server, installing the plotters locally, updating the drivers, downgrading the drivers, repairing AutoCAD, all with brief or no success.

The main thing I cannot work out is it an issue with the drivers or the software, as we have nearly 100+ users with no issues at all, using the same programs and as far as I know the same drivers.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work around.

[Océ Windows Printer Driver](http://global.oce.com/products/tcs500/downloads.aspx) just don't work, cannot fix them so I replaced them with [Océ Adobe® PostScript 3 Drivers (1.14)](http://global.oce.com/products/tcs500/downloads.aspx) and it has stopped it resetting, still need to do some testing, but fingers crossed.

**Update**: After a few days of testing we have found an issues with the PS drivers. For some reason when printing the correct orientation for a roll, it loses a 10-12cm (4-5 inch), down one side, but if printed the other way on it print fine but has to be trimmed down to size.